# Undefined index valor, pegando um valor com o change e adicionando a um input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Opa pessoal estou com um problema e nao consegui encontrar uma solução, pode ser ater simples, porem nao estou enchergando o erro. se poderem me ajudar agradeço! seguinte, fiz um script onde consigo pegar o PREÇO da TABELA "PRODUTOS" e adiconar a um input, o PREÇO do produto é adicionado normalmente, porém ao clicar no submit é mostrado o erro Undefined index preco. Vou mostrar o código logo abaixo.

Esse é o meu HTML, onde seleciono o produto e o valor correspondente.

```
<select name="nome" class="form-control" id="produto" >
          <option>Selecione o produto do pedido </option> 
            <?php
        include_once 'banco.php';
        $pdo = Banco::conectar();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC';
        foreach($pdo->query($sql)as $row){
          echo  '<tr>';
          echo     '<option class="valores" data-valor="'.$row['preco'].'">'.$row['nome'].'</option>';  
          echo  '</tr>';
        }              
         echo '</select><br>';
         ?>    
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="preco">Preço do produto</label><br>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" disabled="disabled" class="form-control select2" style="width: 30%;" placeholder=" 00">
```

Aqui está o erro!!

```
Notice: Undefined index: valor in /opt/lampp/htdocs/orquidariaVersion1.0.1/pages/adm/register_pedidos.php on line 112
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'valor' cannot be null
```

Comment: você tem registros null na coluna Valor, da uma olhada primeiro na sua tabela PRODUCTS.

Comment: Compartilhe todo o seu código para que a comunidade possa te ajudar.